# Sharepoint (MOSS) XSL - PageUrl parameter not being found/displayed

Tags: sharepoint, parameters, xslt

I have a Data View Web Part, on a custom edit Page for a list. I want to grab the current URL and pass it to the next page, so I can return to the editing screen.
I have followed these instructions to display the current page URL:

http://www.stevesofian.net/post/XSLT-Tip-Get-Current-Page-URL.aspx

Inside of Sharepoint Designer, the Url displays and looks fine. HOwever, as soon as I actually view it via the site it goes missing, it's not being displayed at all.

I created a test aspx page (no master page, just a blank aspx), and the exactly the same result occurred.
I've even tried cheating by creating an XSL variable, and using select="$PageUrl", again works in Designer, not on the site.
How can I retrieve the URL?

Answer (score 1):

I get a 404 for the first site you quoted, but, if you import **main.xsl** in your stylesheet, you should be able to get the current page's address by concatenating **$HttpHost** and **$PagePath**:

```
<xsl:import href="/_layouts/xsl/main.xsl"/><!-- before any parameter or variable declarations -->
...
<xsl:value-of select="$HttpHost"/><xsl:value-of select="$PagePath"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the parameter:

```
<xsl:param name="PageUrl" />
```

... doesn't actually work on the web page. Even if you did add in the ParameterBinding line (as suggested above). It does *appear* to work in SP Designer, but when viewed through the browser, the PageUrl parameter returns an empty or Null value. The right parameter to use to return the current page URL is the ServerVariable one. So set up the ParemeterBinding like this:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="PageAddr" Location="ServerVariable(URL)" DefaultValue=""/>
```

The PageAddr is just a random name I'm assigning to the Parameter, which won't be confused with the PageUrl one. Next call the Parameter in the StyleSheet, like this:

```
<xsl:param name="PageAddr" />
```

Now you can call the Parameter anywhere in your XSLT code using $PageAddr ...

Be warned this Parameter doesn't work in SP Designer, but will work in the browser.

Comment: It is possible to add angle brackets by indenting lines of code by 4 spaces or alternatively use `backticks` for inline code.